# Message board Winforms App

Tags: c#, messageboard

I'd like to create a message board like component within my app ie allow users to post messages and communicate.

The app is a C# winforms client using client or server database EF code first.

I'm thinking using the web browser control like an ASP.net page but no server running.

Is this possible? How could this be achieved?

Thanks.

Comment: if you have a winforms app, why would you use a web browser control ? only for arranging the layout of your controls, or did you want to pull something from the web ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your purpose you want to embed a collaboration component into your existing winforms application and want to know if an embedded browser would be the way to go.

There isn't a simple answer but I'll throw up some thoughts:

1. Embedding browsers in winforms apps can be more tedious than you'd think (it's been awhile since I tried so it may have gotten better)

   a. If you do go that route I would suggest looking into an buying a hosted service with an existing message board feature and pointing to that page instead of rolling your own
2. If you do want to control the info you need a way to get messages from one to the others, typically this would be done via a server database and a service layer (or page hosted on the server)

   a. It may be possible to host a web server in your win app but I doubt it's worth the effort if your app needs to be connected to others and/or a server anyways

   b. There are ways to share the data in a peer-to-peer way but it's no simple task

   c. As Bugai suggested you can use standard win forms controls to show messages (albeit not formatted pretty like html very easily unless you go to WPF... etc), if you do I would recommend looking at a RichTextBox or ListBox OR looking into 3rd party control vendors

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use *any control*(web browser, label, textbox or something else) for that. But main is that you need setup server and save messages somewhere on the server.
2. You can communicate between client and server using *server rest api*(post message to a server and get back list of messages).
3. If you want dynamic update of messages, you need send requests to server and ask him for new messages, than if new messages exists send it back to a client and display. Otherwise you can create button like refersh.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I was clear but this seems to do what I am after http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/aspnetruntime/aspnetruntime.asp

However I think I will make my own message control with labels and buttons etc and just build on the fly in a loop...

Thanks.